# how to delete double values in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array like this one:

```
arrayname[1] = "jacob";
arrayname[2] = "peter";
arrayname[3] = "jacob";
arrayname[4] = "nicholas";
```

I want to remove the double jacob so it will be like

```
arrayname[1] = "jacob";
arrayname[2] = "peter";
arrayname[3] = "nicholas";
```

How do I do that?

Comment: @fayer, if you indent your code with at least four spaces it will format properly. I fixed this question, but for future reference.

Comment: Questions like this can easily be answered by just browsing the PHP Array Documentation and reading the function names.

Answer (score 9):

[`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/array_unique)

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```